Aura Component focus not working
In Salesforce aura: When I am trying to focus the header element in modal, when opened by aura parent button, the focus is not working? Need the focus to work
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <lightning:button label="Open Modal" onclick="{!c.openModal}"/>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalHeader">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 id="modalHeader" class="slds-text-heading_medium">Modal Header</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content">
                    <!-- Modal content here -->
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button label="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModal}"/>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>

Js
({
    openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                // Focus on the modal header when the modal opens
                var header = component.find("modalHeader");
                if (header) {
                    header.focus();
                }
            }), 0
        );
    },

    closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
    }
})


You definitely should use "aura:id" instead of "id". In addition to that - don't you want to wait a little bit longer than 0 seconds until your HTML is rendered?

Assign an aura:id to the header element so you can easily reference it in your JavaScript controller. Also, Make sure you're using component.find correctly to get the header element and Use the focus() method to set the focus on the header element.
Markup::
<aura:component>
        <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

        <lightning:button label="Open Modal" onclick="{!c.openModal}"/>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
                <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalHeader">
                        <div class="slds-modal__container">
                                <header class="slds-modal__header" aura:id="modalHeader">
                                        <h2 id="modalHeader" class="slds-text-heading_medium">Modal Header</h2>
                                </header>
                                <div class="slds-modal__content">
                                        <!-- Modal content here -->
                                </div>
                                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                                        <lightning:button label="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModal}"/>
                                </footer>
                        </div>
                </section>
        </aura:if>
</aura:component>

JS::
({
        openModal: function(component, event, helper) {
                component.set("v.isModalOpen", true);
                window.setTimeout(
                        $A.getCallback(function() {
                                var header = component.find("modalHeader");
                                if (header) {
                                        header.getElement().focus();
                                }
                        }), 0
                );
        },

        closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
                component.set("v.isModalOpen", false);
        }
})

